# VIM color scheme error

Tags: vim

Vim keeps telling me

```
E185: Cannot fine color scheme wombat256
```

even though this .vim file is in the correct directory.

When I do :colorscheme wombat256 from within the editor it works but from within the vimrx file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exact error and the colorscheme line from your .vimrc?  Either you typed in that error or vim has a typo in the error message.  Just want to verify the exact message and setting.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are using "`colorscheme wombat256`" before you have set up your `runtimepath` option.

If you include the contents of your `.vimrc` then it will be easier to see.